# How to specify datatype of a column in excel before MySql exports to it?

Tags: mysql, excel

My apologies if this question may have been asked before but I'm currently stumped.

I'm running a query in MySql that looks like this:

```
SELECT 'ClientID', 'ContractID', 'Capital_Opening_Bal', 'Capital_Financed', 'Transaction_Date', 'Cap_Int_Day', 'Cap_Debit_Orders',
'Vat', 'Other_Entries_Capital', 'Adjustments_Capital', 'Capital_Int_For_Month', 'Capital_Closing_Bal', 
'Arrear_Opening_Bal', 'Due', 'Receipts', 'Rejections', 'Other_Entries_Arrears', 'Adjustments_Arrear', 'Arrear_Int_For_Month', 'Arrear_Closing_Bal'

UNION

(SELECT ClientID, ContractID, Capital_Opening_Bal, Capital_Financed, Transaction_Date, Cap_Int_Day, Cap_Debit_Orders,
Vat, Other_Entries_Capital, Adjustments_Capital, Capital_Int_For_Month, Capital_Closing_Bal, 
Arrear_Opening_Bal, Due, Receipts, Rejections, Other_Entries_Arrears, Adjustments_Arrear, Arrear_Int_For_Month, Arrear_Closing_Bal

FROM sapor.capital_and_arrear_movement

into OUTFILE "C:/IMPORT FILE/TEST.CSV"

FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n');
```

It exports it to the file correctly but one thing is amiss;

My ClientID and ContractID columns in MySql appear as such:

> 000356 000321 002415 000021

But in Excel they turn out like this:

> 356 321 2415 21

From my understanding excel is reading them as integers and removing the "superfluous" 0s even though the columns' datatypes in MySql are VARCHAR(6).

Is there any way to prevent Excel from changing the datatype/removing the 0s?

Comment: You aren't exportint to Excel. You are generating a CSV file - just a text file with commas. There are no types in text files. Why don't you try to generate a real Excel (xlsx) file? Anyway, Excel itself *imports* a CSV file when you double-click on it using default settings. You can speficy your own if you go to to `Data>FromText`. Or you can force Excel to treat everything as text by prepending a single quote (`'`)

Comment: if you open the csv with a txt editor (notepad if you use windows for example) you will see the data with the leading 0. Then import the file in excel via the data -> load from CSV tool and not opening directly with excel. You will be prompted by Excel to format each column as you want and you can set it as text